# ChakraProvider not working in NextJs react v16.4.0 but works with react v17.0.1

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

When trying to add ChakraProvider to my NextJs app root I get the error:

Uncaught Error:expected a string. You forgot export your component from the file its defined,or you might have mixed up default/named import

```
 <Provider store={store}>
  <DefaultSeo {...SEO} />
  <ChakraProvider>
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  </ChakraProvider>
</Provider>
```

After updating to react v17.0.1 the error doesn't show up.

Why does ChakraProvider fail to work with React v16.4.0?